# Thread about socket communication

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I want to make function that when receive buffer from socket,  thread make whole program freeze out of my function until my function is finished. I try these as below

Function Listen

```
void Listen(can* _c) {

    while (true)
    {

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>guard(_c->connection->mutex);
        thread t(&connect_tcp::Recv_data,_c->connection,_c->s,ref(_c->response),_c->signals);
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();

    }

}
```

Function dataset_browseCan

```
void dataset_browseCan(can* _c) {
    thread org_th(Listen, _c); // I call thread here
    org_th.detach();
    dataset_browse(_c->cotp, _c->mms_obj, _c->connection, _c->response, _c->list, _c->size_encoder, _c->s);
    dataset_signals_browse(_c->cotp, _c->mms_obj, _c->connection, _c->response, _c->list, _c->size_encoder, _c->s);

    Sleep(800);
    _c->signals = new Signals[_c->response.real_signals_and_values.size()];

}
```

Function Recv Data

```
void connect_tcp::Recv_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response,Signals *signals) {
    LinkedList** list = new LinkedList * [1000];
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t [10000];
    Sleep(800);
    /*std::lock_guard<std::mutex>guard(mutex);*/
    thread j(recv,s, (char*)buffer, 10000, 0);
    j.join()
    /*this->mutex.unlock();*/
    decode_bytes(response,buffer, list,signals);

}
```

I tried mutex and this_thread::sleep_for() but everytime my main function keep running. 
Is make program freeze possible ?

Comment: I don't know where to start, this has so many issues. To just start with the first: In `Listen`, the thread `t` is utterly pointless. The calling thread blocks while another thread executes. You should just call `Recv_data` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use threads in order to *allow* things to keep running while something else is happening, so wanting to "stop `main`" seems counter-intuitive.

However, if you want to share data between threads (e.g. between the thread that runs `main` and a background thread) then you need to use some form of synchronization. One way to do that is to use a `std::mutex`. If you lock the mutex before every access, and unlock it afterwards (using `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`) then it will prevent another thread from locking the same mutex while you are accessing the data.

If you need to prevent concurrent access for a long time, then you should not hold a mutex for the whole time. Either consider whether threads are the best solution to your problem, or use a mutex-protected flag to indicate whether the data is ready, and then either poll or use `std::condition_variable` or similar to wait until the flag is set.